# Windows Server 2012/16 "administrator password is blank" on Google Cloud

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, google-cloud-platform, windows-server-2016

When I try to setup Active Directory on Windows Server 2012 or 2016 on Google Cloud (using the default VM images with Desktop Experience), it fails on creating a forest with the error:

> ...The local Administrator account becomes the domain Administrator account when you create a new domain. The new domain cannot be created because the local Administrator account password does not meet requirements.
>
> Currently, the local Administrator password is blank, which might lead to security issues...

This is unexpected, because

1. The administrator password is a very secure password generated by Google.
2. I am trying this on fresh servers using a completely default setup.
3. I am following the directions at [tenforums](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/51456-windows-server-2016-setup-local-domain-controller.html)
4. I even found a video of these directions working from two years ago on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpdNp27yp-w)

Attempted solutions which did not work:

- Rebooting
- Changing the administrator password using CTRL-ALT-DELETE and using control panel
- Connecting using remote desktop from both Ubuntu and Windows 8
- Changing the domain name to something which is not a public URL

I have no idea what is going on, so even hints on where to start would be helpful.

**UPDATE**

It appears there are two separate accounts (my default account and an account named 'Administrator') even though only one account shows up in Control Panel User Settings. I followed [Google's directions](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploy-fault-tolerant-active-directory-environment) to setup AD, but they fail when I run

```
net use Administrator *
```

with the error

```
System error 67 has occurred.

The network name cannot be found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's directions work perfectly. The directions from TenForum and YouTube also work as long as you run this command:

```
net user Administrator *
```

from a PowerShell window. PowerShell must be run as Administrator (right click on the icon to find the option). Note that the command is `user` *not* `use`.

Answer (score 5):

Using Control Panel, choose: User Accounts|User Accounts|Manage another account, you will find an "Administrator" account, a "Guest" account besides your current administrator account. Your current administrator account is Password protected. Create a password for the "Administrator" account, then the problem is solved.